# Proving divisibility with modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

Having three integers a,b,n can I prove $n|(a-b)$ by simply proving that $(a-b)\equiv 0\pmod n$.

For example, to prove that
$11|(15^{11}-13^{11}-2^{11})$
we can proceed as follows

$$
\begin{split}
(15^{11}-13^{11}-2^{11}) &\equiv (15-13-2) \pmod {11}
\quad \text{Fermat's little theorem}\\
15-13-2 &= 0
\end{split}
$$

$(15^{11}-13^{11}-2^{11})\equiv 0\pmod {11}$ proves $11|(15^{11}-13^{11}-2^{11})$

Is it correct?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Note that $a - b \equiv 0 \mod n$ and $n | a - b$ are *equivalent* statements i.e. proving one is tantamount to proving the other.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Please excuse a personal question but I've been wondering -- what is the connection between Aston Villa, Olof Mellberg and your nickname, written in Ukrainian? Thanks for satisfying my curiosity :-)

Comment: @gt6989b Favourite Football Club  - Aston Villa. Favourite Villa defender - Olof Mellberg. Favourite Script - Slav. Almost no  further connection : I have not been to Villa's stadium, never met Olof Mellberg , but I did go to Russia for 20 days. From there I picked up this name, and loved it. In fact, I am quite far away from this : My native language is Tamil(and I write Hindi poems in free time).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thank you so much :-), i figured you were his fan, but the Russian connection was interesting, especially with a nickname written in Ukrainian :-)

Comment: @gt6989b Thank you. I do not wish to change this name anytime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly correct; I'd write $15-13-2\equiv0\pmod{11}$ to go along with the argument. It would work the same if, instead of $15$, you have $26$ or $4$.

By the way, you might prove even more: for what positive integer $n$ does
$$
11\mid (15^n-13^n-2^n)
$$
hold? Well, this is the same as saying
$$
4^n-2\cdot2^n\equiv0\pmod{11}
$$
which becomes
$$
4^n\equiv2\cdot2^n\pmod{11}
$$
and, dividing by $2^n$ (which is possible, prove it),
$$
2^n\equiv 2\pmod{11}
$$
or again
$$
2^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{11}
$$
Now $2^2\not\equiv1$ and $2^5\not\equiv1$; therefore the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $11$ has to be $10$ (it *has* to be a divisor of $10$). Then we conclude that $n-1$ has to be a multiple of $10$.